# Complete intersections and algebraic independence

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a smooth projective variety over an 
algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ such as $k = \mathbb{C}$.

1. Is the intersection of hypersurfaces $H_i = (f_i = 0)$ with $f_1, \ldots, f_r$ algebraically independent (irreducible?) homogeneous polynomials a complete intersection? From the definition using the number of generators from the homogeneous ideal and the idea of elements of a regular sequence being ``independent'' from each other, it looks like this should be the case. However, most of the results that I found on complete intersections and algebraically independent polynomials seem to add additional conditions for this kind of thing to be true. Am I missing something here?
2. When is $\bigcap H_i$ smooth and irreducible? In particular, I don't see what what is not ``generic'' about this intersection (i.e. why it would be a case where something goes wrong in the proof of the Bertini theorem).

Comment: I am not sure I understand. But, $x,xy$ are algebraically independent, but do not give a complete intersection. If you want irreducible, take $x,y, xz+yt$. In light of this, I am not sure what you mean in 2.

Comment: Thank you! For 2, I was just wondering what kinds of conditions can be used to show that an intersection of hypersurfaces is smooth and irreducible. Can we still get something smooth even if we don't have a complete intersection? If so, how would we do this?

Comment: Any smooth variety is an intersection of (many) hypersurfaces, so you can get such. So, what exactly do you want?

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to know when the intersection of (algebraically independent) hypersurfaces is smooth.